# DateTime Conversion and Parsing DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format, data-conversion

I store some DateTime in a CSV log with:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

When I try to read it I found something like:

```
"05/15/2012 10:09:28.650"
```

The problem is when I try to cast it as a DateTime again...

```
DateTime.Parse("05/15/2012 10:09:28.650");
```

Throws an Exception "Invalid DateTime" or something like that...

How can I properly re-read the DateTime?

Comment: Have a look at [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("05/15/2012 10:09:28.650",
                                format,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss) with specifying the format

```
String dateStr=DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff");
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: you made my day here is a vup

Answer (score 1):

You should use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) method to parse your string. You would have to make a class, imlementing IFormatProvider, but if you want to use a custom DateTime format, it's the best method I can think of.