# c# string date format from d.M.yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datetime, date-format

Please, how I can convert date string from my csv import to grid and mysql database?

I import date in dd.MM.yyyy format and I must format yyyy-MM-dd for mysql database.

my code for datagrid rows is

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(counter, "1", lineIn[0], ControlPrice, lineIn[3]);
```

lineIn[0] is date string...
Thank you

Comment: are you sure lineIn[0] has a valid date and isn't blank? if you are to pass lineInl[0] to any function, I assume its an object so you you will need to convert to string first, if you are to use DateTime.ParseExact. See my example below

Comment: could you put some CSV data into your example above?

Answer (score 2):

Its best to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Based on your example, you need to cast to string before passing to the function.

You should also consider what happens if an invalid date is in the CSV, how do you want to handle that? Or do you always expect a date and want to halt processing?

Here's a LinqPad example I used to test:

```
object date = "12.2.2014";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), "d.M.yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See this SO post for more info: 
[DateTime Conversion and Parsing DateTime.Now.ToString(“MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599209/datetime-conversion-and-parsing-datetime-now-tostringmm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-fff)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case your record might come as blank, it will give error while parsing to datetime, so I have added a condition to check for blank and then converted it to the required format.

```
If(lineIn[0].ToString() != "")
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(counter, "1", DateTime.ParseExact(lineIn[0].ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ControlPrice, lineIn[3]);
}
else
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(counter, "1", "", ControlPrice, lineIn[3]);
}
```

Comment: thank you but system say = "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @kubis, can you please show some test data that is returned in lineIn[0]

Comment: here is import data from csv...
1.2.2014,334.00 Kč,,Jana vyplata

Comment: I also think some dates must be coming as blank, I have modified my answer to check blanks, please see if it works

Comment: @rene, I have mentioned in my above comment that the error might be coming because of blanks in some output, so I have modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
        var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lineIn[0], "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
        string dateStringInAnotherFormat = parsedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```